# Using 'that' with 'who', 'whom', 'which'

Tags: that, who-that

```
A child that, who becomes
A child that becomes
A child who becomes
A child who, that becomes
```

Which is more appropriate and which ones are wrong if any?

The problem is not if they are interchangeable or not rather if I can use them both at the same time. My punctuation may be off, if you can correct that as well, I'll be happy.

Comment: I'm asking if they can both be used at the same time, not if they are interchangeable or not when to use which.

Comment: If I'd noticed that, I'd have simply closevoted for lack of prior research. Whatever gave you the idea it *might* be possible to string together two  relative pronouns like that?

Comment: Editing your question has not removed the duplication caused by the middle two suggestions. Asking about the grammaticality of the first and last suggestions is off-topic as being unresearched and too basic.